# replacing an object in listview with new one?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `listview` with few items. I am using foreach loop to check if there is a match. The code I am using looks like this:

```
foreach (ListViewItem test in listView1.Items)
{
   if (test.SubItems[1].ToString() == item.SubItems[1].ToString())
   {
      test.Tag = item.Tag;
   }
}
```

What I am trying to do is, check the 2nd index and if there is a match replace the old item 'test' with the new one 'item'.

Apparently there is no change in the listview. Is the way I am replacing the object wrong?

Comment: my question is why there is no change in the listview item? am i incorrectly replacing it?

Comment: what kind of change did you expect to see? `Tag` property is simple holder for what ever value you want and it is't scanned, bound to by list view item.

Comment: show your code how you bind the list view and what is 'item'?

Comment: @Rafal the change i am expecting is the values stored in 'test' items should be replaced by 'item'. basically it is updating the listview if there is similar items.

Comment: @Liban changing tag will not accomplish your goal. Try both answers provided those might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can clone the item and assign directly to the list view item. but you need to change foreach loop to for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].ToString() == item.SubItems[1].ToString())
    {
        listView1.Items[i] = (ListViewItem)item.Clone();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have updated the *Tag* only. You need to change test.SubItems[0], test.SubItems[1],... to see the changes.

Or you could remove old item and insert new item by using `listView1.Items.Remove(...)` or `listView1.Items.RemoveAt(...)` and `listView1.Items.Insert(...)`. But if you need to pay account of performance you should use the first algorithm (changing test.SubItems[i]).

Comment: Actually i tried to update the SubItems[i] using a loop, and it works. but is there a way that i can update the whole item instead of changing all the subitems? i guess the 'items' is an listview object that contains the whole SubItems.